# Attrs validation checking when an attribute is another attrs object

Tags: python, validation, python-attrs

I have two attrs classes, where one is an attribute of the other. I want to ensure that if a particular value is given to one, there's a particular value in the other.

I've looked at validators, and don't think there's anything that captures this.

Here's what I've written:

```py
@attr.s
class C:
    a = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(str))

@attr.s
class D:
    x = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(str))
    z = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(C))

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        if self.x == "a":
            assert self.z.a == "a12"
        elif self.x == "b":
            assert self.z.a == "b12"
        elif self.x == "c":
            assert self.z.a == "c12"


d = D(x="a", z=C("a12"))
```

I think this works, but i sense perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What's the point of having two attributes if there's a required relationship between them?

Comment: I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work. The `C` object is fully initialized before `D()` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine, except that you probably shouldn't use `assert` in production code (they get optimized out when you run `python -O`).

*If* z came after *x*, you could also use a [decorator validator](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#decorator) that get a partially initialized instance as an argument, but I find you solution more robust, since it doesn't depend on the order of the attribute definitions.

Comment: thank you, I didn't realise that ordering mattered re "z after x", so I'll have to read into that :)

Comment: It only matters when using decorator validators, because the validators run in the order the attributes are defined and get the hitherto initialized instance passed as `self`. If you use `__attrs_post_init__` you’re on the safe side; all attributes are already initialized when it runs.